# Cannot display a alert inside onNewIntent()

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-pendingintent

I have a problem with displaying alert inside `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` function. Pending Intent extra is retrieved correctly and it's value is logged as expected, but the alert isn't displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        String value = extras.getString("message");
        Log.v("alert", value);  // <--- this line works fine.


        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("title");
        alertDialog.setMessage(value);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();

Comment: @Santhosh - Correct! Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
```

Comment: I don't understand why ``YourActivity.this != this``